# Perl - system Chinese filename

Tags: perl, system, filenames

Can anyone explain why my file name is display wrong and how to fix it? I want the filename is 游戏美术.txt3

I'm using Debian 6, Perl v5.10.1
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("echo 游戏美术 > 游戏美术.txt3");
system ("cat 游戏美术.txt3");
```

Output:
cat: 游戏美术.txt3: No such file or directory

I try to remove txt3 file: rm -r *.txt3
rm: remove regular file `游\346\217美术.txt3'?

Filename is displayed as 游??美术.txt3 in my console. I can cat it, the content is display correctly but not filename.

Thanks a lot.

Update 1:
I have tested the 2 codes above on Debian 7, perl v5.14.2 and Ubuntu 12.04 perl v5.14.2. They work fine.

Update 2:
With Debian 6, perl v5.10.1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system ("touch 游戏美术.txt4");
```

It can create the file 游戏美术.txt4 correctly. I meant the filename in Chinese.

What can I do with "system("echo 游戏美术 > 游戏美术.txt3");" to create the correct filename? Not 游??美术.txt3

Thanks!

Comment: `system ("ls 游戏美术");` Surely you just wanted `system("ls")`, since it's a file in the current directory. Or alternatively `system("ls -d 游戏美术.txt3")` (not forgetting the `.txt3` bit).

Comment: Some characters may be displayed by `ls` as `?` if they are otherwise unprintable. This makes sense, as `?` in a glob expression matches anything, and thus also the intended filename. The filename itself is still intact – e.g. you can display it like `perl -E'say for <*.txt3>'` (assuming an Unicode locale)

Comment: Thanks all for reply. Edited the post. Actually, I want to cat the file but the system cannot find it. How can I cat it since the command system("echo 游戏美术 > 游戏美术.txt3"); make the filename wrong with ?? characters

Comment: Works for 1. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` 2. gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1, character encoding Unicode (UTF-8); 3. Perl script, UTF-8 Unicode. Please make sure your locale setting could support Chinese correctly.

Comment: I have just tested on wheezy (debian 7) with perl v5.14.2. It works as expected. Maybe this because by perl v5.10.1. The same locale LANG=en_US.utf8

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Perl as if it's the shell.  I suggest you use the shell to be the shell, or you use the Perl module File::Copy to do your file copying for you.